# How to skip logs period for logstash?

Tags: logstash

I have run a logstash from an user and now, I have created `logstash` user. The problem of running the script from the new user is that I have to wait until it loads all the logs until now. It does not know what logstash has done in the run of the previous user. Is there a possibility to run it starting with a date, like yesterday, or today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you really need to do is copy your sincedb from the old user to the new user.  It should be the directory `$HOME/.sincedb` of the old user.

Comment: How to do this? I have no access from one user to the other, and in `root` I do not see any file in `$HOME/`

Comment: so as the old user (is that `root`?) if you do a ls -ld $HOME/.sincedb you don't see the directory (.named files don't show up on ls normally).

Comment: ok, it is not `root`, let's say `user_old` and `user_new`. How do I copy the `/home/user_old/.sincedb_544643dfg65g6sdf` to `/home/user_new/`?

Comment: you would need someone with access to the old user (ie root or the old user).  They could then copy the directory to someplace readable (`cp -r /home/olduser/.sincedb /tmp`) and set the permissions correctly (`chmod -R a+r /tmp/.sincedb; chmod a+x /tmp/.sincedb`), and then as the `logstash` user, `cp -r /tmp/.sincedb $HOME`

Answer (score 0):

You could use a drop though to just discard things before this date.